# Schema hasn't been registered for model "ModuleSchema"

Tags: mongoose, nestjs, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate, nestjs-mongoose

I'm trying to figure out how to register a model in NestJs, cause I allways get an error saying:

```
Use mongoose.model(name, schema) {"0":"MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model \"ModuleSchema\".\nUse mongoose.model(name, schema)\n    at NativeConnection.Connection.model (F:\\Code\\thorberg\\divo-backend\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\connection.js:1132:11)\n`
```

My goal is to use the mongoose populate method to join a referenced document in a other collection.

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { CreateModuleDto } from './dto/create-module.dto';
import { UpdateModuleDto } from './dto/update-module.dto';
import { Module, ModuleDocument } from './module.model';

@Injectable()
export class ModuleService {
  constructor(@InjectModel(Module.name) private moduleModule: Model<ModuleDocument>) { }


  findAll() {
    return this.moduleModule.find().populate('modules');
  }
}
```

I tried as such and that did work. But don't think this is best practice:

```
 findAll() {
    return this.moduleModule.find().populate('modules', ['name', 'isChecked'], this.moduleModule);
  }
```

Is there a way to register that Model somewhere In module.module.ts?

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { ModuleController } from './module.controller';
import { Module as M, ModuleSchema } from './module.model';
import { ModuleService } from './module.service';


@Module({
  imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: M.name, schema: ModuleSchema }])],
  controllers: [ModuleController],
  providers: [ModuleService],
  exports: [ModuleService]
})
export class ModuleModule { }
```

Comment: Can you show the `ModuleModule` where you call `MongooseModule.forFeature()` for the `ModuleModel`?

Comment: I've added the Module in the questions above!

Answer (score 0):

mainly there are two reasons for getting this error

1. may be forget to import model and schema in module
2. maybe forgot to add or change of the refer value in schema,
   example

```
  @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Module" })
  modules: mongoose.ObjectId;
```

here ref must be the name of class, ie

```
@Schema({
  collection: "modules",
})
export class Module  {}
```

**classname** of this model.
please check